# How to call a variable within a Redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

How do I call a variable, such as `device_id`, `device_name`, or `group_id` within the `device` state in Redux?

`{JSON.stringify(device.deviceData)}` works great and displays all the state information within `deviceData`, but `{JSON.stringify(device.deviceData.device_id)}` doesn't show any information.

Given the `0` pin, I also tried `{JSON.stringify(device.deviceData.0.device_id)}` but this resulted in an error. I wouldn't want to work with that solution anyway though since I want this call to be universal instead of assigning a specific number in that call.

My Redux state is screenshotted below

[image]

Comment: deviceData looks to be an array (index 0) so you need deviceData[0].device_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deviceData` appears to be an array. So you may access the first item like this: `device.deviceData[0].device_id`

> How could I make that universal, in pseudo-terms: device.deviceData[all indexes].device_id if I wanted to make a list of the device_id's for example?

You can use array.map to create a new array with only the device_ids.

```js
const device_ids = device.deviceData.map((data) => data.device_id);
```

Comment: How could I make that universal, in pseudo-terms: `device.deviceData[all indexes].device_id` if I wanted to make a list of the device_id's for example?

Comment: @Henrik I have updated my answer to address your question!